# Xcode ignores my frameworks

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I get the following error for all the frameworks I use:

```
ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A334)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386).
```

I am using these frameworks in other projects and they all work.  Just this one is causing this issue.  Project and target settings seem to be the same.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error message states that you're including a framework for ARM (iOS) when compiling for i386 (Mac OS X).

That will not work.

Comment: This is really weird.  Architecture is armv6 armv7, Base SDK is Latest iOS (iOS 5.0) and I get all these errors.  After your comment I changes Base SDK to Mac just for curiosity and now those errors are gone.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @saman01 *Very* strange message for it, but if the framework starts working when you switch to x86, it would seem to be the other way, the framework is x86 and the SDK is ARM.

Comment: I just noticed as soon as I opened scheme for editing it changed from iPhone to Mac.  I don't even have a choice of iPhone anymore.  Perhaps my xcode is corrupted.  I wonder if anyone had similar experience.

Comment: This happens when you share the project files with other developers. Go to the location where your .xcodeproj file is located, right click on it, choose 'Show package contents' and delete project.xcworkspace and xcuserdata.

Comment: @lawicko Ah, you learn something new every day. I never had that happen, but I've always ignored those files in git so they're not checked in in the first place.